# Passing closure as an argument to another closure in Jenkins Groovy

Tags: groovy, jenkins-pipeline, closures, jenkins-groovy, jenkins-job-dsl

I need to pass a closure as an argument to another closure, not sure if below should work or what is the way to make it work

```
Closure Build(String imageName, String testCommand){
    Closure testImage = { imageName ->
        sh('''cd ''' + dir + ''' \
            && if make image ''' + imageName''' 2>&1 | grep -m 1 "No rule to make target"; then exit 1; fi''',
            returnStatus: true
        )
    }

    Closure runTests = { imageName ->
        makeResult = runWithCommand(imageName, testImage(imageName))
        if (makeResult != 0) {
        runWithCommand(imageName, testCommand)
        }
    }
}

def runWithCommand(image_ref, t_command) {

    sh'''#!/bin/bash
        docker run --rm -i '''image_ref ''' /bin/bash -c \'''' + t_command + '''\'
    '''
}
```

In above code testImage is a closure which is passed to another function in groovy, not sure if it is the right way and it works?

Comment: It is certainly possible to pass a Closure as a method argument.

Comment: @MattSchuchard: I don't have a test pipeline to test, not sure if above logic would work or not